# Getting 400 bad request reason:required from google cloud stoarge json api

Tags: json, http, google-cloud-storage, bad-request

I am attempting to upload a file (png in this this example) to google cloud storage but my request fails with the following 400 Bad Request response.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required"
 }
}
```

My POST request looks like this.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/unit_tests/o?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript
Authorization: OAuth XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Content-Type: image/png
Host: www.googleapis.com
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive

96DA5
�PNG

���
IHDR����������e�����sRGB�������gAMA����
�a���   pHYs�������o�d����IDATx^�|W��?o��������������,Y`I

*** FIDDLER: RawDisplay truncated at 128 characters. Right-click to disable truncation. ***
```

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) I've supplied the necessary paramters etc so I cannot see what is **required** that I am not providing.

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `name` parameter? [docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#simple)

Comment: you are right. make it an answer and i'll accept

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to supply the `name` parameter in the URL. See the [Simple upload](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload#simple) documentation for more details.